# LINQ to SQL read the id just insert and roll back

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Here is my problem,
I want to get the ID from what I just inserted and use it as a foreign key for another table.

```
Records record = new Records {
  field1 = 1;
  field2 = 2; 
}; 
DataContext.Records.InsertOnSubmit(record); 
DataContext.SubmitChanges(); // transaction 1
int recordID = record.ID;

tblDEMO demo = new tblDEMO {
  rID = recordID
  field1 = 1;
}; 
DataContext.tblDEMOs.InsertOnSubmit(demo); 
sparxdc.SubmitChanges(); // transaction 2
```

My question is, If I do this it will create 2 transactions. How can I rollback the 1st one if the 2nd is fail??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with both submits within one transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        perform first submit
        perform second submit
    }
    finally
    {
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Is there a better way to do this (without 2 submit)?

Answer (score 0):

Add any number of calls to InsertOnSubmit / Delete methods and call SubmitChanges when done with all the changes. Within one TransactionScope either manually created Transaction.

Comment: But I have to read the ID before insert to another table. That is why I have the do SubmitChanges() twice.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly if your entities are related (if there is a relation in database) you can make so

```
var order = new Order();
Order.Customer = new Customer(); // here both order and customer represent your entities
dbContext.InsertOnSubmit();
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Could you give some more information?

Comment: Yes they are related. My demo has a foreign key rid relate to the record table ID.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know what to do now.
Insert 2 table which are related with foreign key, we need to do this.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
Order order = new Order();
customer.Order.Add(order);
DataContext.Customer.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
```